# Сжать активность при появлении клавиатуры

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-edittext, клавиатура

Есть Navigation Drawer Activity, есть фрагмент, который запускается с него. Есть поле ввода (editText) и кнопки под ним. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на editText, кнопки появлялись над клавиатурой, а не клавиатура закрывала их видимость? Советовали в манифесте для активити просписать такое `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` пробовал но не оказывает никакого влияния.

xml фрагмента

Корневой layout LinearLayout почему-то не показывается в сообщении, с параметрами `android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <******.*********.rest.DynamicImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivWord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/emty_picture" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvWord"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="word"
        android:textColor="@color/colorYellow"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.4">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEnterWord"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorGrey"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/etHintEnterWord"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</FrameLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnHelp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorYellow"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/btnHelp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCheck"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="@color/colorYellow"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/btnCheck"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="30dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Пример того, чего хочу добиться на скриншоте программы duolingvo.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А это пробовали: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`?

Comment: Да пробовал, это все советуют.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что трабла в разметке xml.

Comment: Ну, приведите тогда и разметку в вопросе - может вам кто с утра и поможет) У меня идей больше нет, а все остальные спят)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

все оказалось просто, помимо записи в манифесте   `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` нужно еще было в последнем `LinearLayout` убрать вес и по высоте поставить wrap_content и получаем вот такую красоту))))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри кажется есть готовая библиотека под названием `SizeAdjustingTextView`